# The number of elements in a set given the probability of selecting 2 of the same type of elements

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

A bag contains $3$ red  marbles, $4$ blue marbles and $X$ green marbles. Given that the probability of choosing 2 green marbles is $\frac 5{26}$ calculate the number of marbles in the bag.

I really don't know how to approach this question I tried to solve for $\binom x2 = \frac 5{26}$ but I'd also need the number of green marbles.
I've figured that $n$ (the number of marbles) $> 9$ or else there would be a probability of $0$ of pulling out $2$ green

Comment: Probability of drawing $2$ green marbles is $\frac{X}{3+4+X} \cdot \frac{X-1}{3+4+X-1} = \frac{5}{26}$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Note:  you should specify whether the two marbles are chosen with or without replacement.

Comment: @lulu the question does not say, it's from a mock paper for Higher Irish Leaving Cert Maths. Is the question easier to solve with or without replacement?

Comment: As it happens, it has to be "without replacement".  If you were replacing, then the probability that a given draw is green would be $\frac X{7+X}$ so the probability of getting two green in a row would be the square of that.  But $\frac 5{26}$ is not the square of a rational number.  Still, the writer ought to have specified.

Answer (score 0):

**If the marbles are taken without replacement.**

The total number of sets of $2$ elements that could be formed with all of the marbles (there are $X + 3 +4 = X +7$ marbles) is $\binom{X+7}{2}$.

The total number of sets of $2$ elements that can be formed with all of the marbles is $\binom{X}{2}$.

Thus the probability of taking $2$ green marbles is $ G(X) = \frac{\binom{X}{2}}{\binom{X+7}{2}}$, thus solving for $G(X) = \frac{5}{26}$ gives :
$$
26 X(X-1) =  5(X+7)(X+6)\\
26 X^2 -26X =  5X^2 + 65X+210\\
0 =  21 X^2 - 91X -210\
$$
Six is a root of this equation so I claim $X=6$.
You can check it by solving it, or using a solver.

**If the marbles are taken with replacement.**

Then solve $\frac{X^2}{(X+7)^2} = \frac{5}{26}$. It has no integer roots, so your problem is probably without replacement.